# Animate Progress Bar with start time and end time in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate a progress bar with js/jquery.

I have the start time like this: "2020-02-21 05:38:33" and the end time: "2020-02-21 05:41:43".
I think this could maybe be calculated with the current time and the start and end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample progress bar with Bootstrap, jQuery & momentjs. Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var start = moment('2020-02-21 05:38:33');
  var end = moment('2020-02-21 20:00:00');
  var formattedPercentage = 0;
  
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var now = moment();
    var percentage = now.diff(start) / end.diff(start) * 100;

    if (percentage > 100) {
      formattedPercentage = 100;
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      formattedPercentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
    }
    // Use formattedPercentage as you need
    $('#example-progress-bar .progress-bar').width(formattedPercentage+'%').html(formattedPercentage+'%')

  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="example-progress-bar" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```